# PHP Insert Into Statement always fails

Tags: php, mysql

I am making myself a website and I am onto the backend administration section, I'm currently stuck on submitting the details from a form into my database, however I keep getting the same error over and over again no matter what, which is:

> Error: 
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your >MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Change) VALUES ('Connor', >'Connor')' at line 1

This is the code which is giving me the error (it connects perfectly to the database):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO changes (DevName,Change) VALUES ('$dev', '$changed')";

$a = mysql_query($query);
```

It keeps saying syntax error when I have been looking at other code, and it shows the exact same thing as the code that I have (except the variables of course).

Comment: `Change` is a reserved word in the `SQL` language. You have to put backticks around it: ` Change `.

Comment: @arkascha That did it, that worked. Thanks! I'm getting _1 record added_ output now!

Comment: You are welcome. Have fun :-)

Comment: Fred, I had no idea what was wrong with it, so how could I possibly find that answer?

Comment: @Fred-ii- is a virtual robot living here on SO. So he knows all questions by heart.

Comment: `$a = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` -  `...right syntax to use near 'Change)` is what you would have seen. Most common error made; not checking for errors. It's said countless time. If I got nickel for everytime that's said; we'd all retire ;-) Edit: Just like the error stated and told you.

Comment: *"Fred, I had no idea what was wrong with it, so how could I possibly find that answer?"* - **A:** You Google your error? ;-) and for probable subsequent errors? In turn possibly avoiding questions and for you to learn how to debug code. No better way to learn than *from your mistakes* ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's cause [`Change is a reserve word in MySQL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html).. You will have to escape it using backtique.

The following works fine, otherwise explosions:

```
create table changes
(   DevName varchar(100),
    `Change` varchar(100)
);

insert changes(DevName,`Change`) values ('1','2');
```

Comment: All fine, happens. Have fun :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please **don't use mysql_*** methods because they are deprecated in PHP5.5 and removed in PHP7. Instead of that you should **use PDO or mysqli**

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO changes ('DevName', 'Change') VALUES (:dev, :changed)');
$sth->bindParam(':dev', $dev, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindParam(':changed', $changed, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
$sth->execute();
```

For more details about PDO visit site http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764908/pdostatement-use-grave-accents-in-columns